# custom database query with Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, pyodbc

I have a large database (more than 5 million rows) accessible with microsoft access.
I am able so far to pull the entire table in a data frame with python but this is very long to be processed (more than 15 minutes) which is nuts as I only need to work on a much smaller section of the entire table ...

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


conn_str(
r'DRIVER = {Adaptive Server Enterprise};'
r'DBQ = \\path_where_the_table_is_located.mdb;'
r'SERVER = server_name;'
r'Databse = ...;'
r'UID = xxx;'
r'PWD = xxx;'
r'port = xxx')


con = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

df  = pd.read_sql('select * table_to_be_converted_into_a_df, conn)
```

how can I enhance my query above to only request a smaller portion of the entire table and run it much faster ?

```
df1 = df.loc[df['date'] == '2021-07-07']
```

this is the code I run to shrink the df once it's done and that I would like to add somehow to the initial query to ONLY query the data I need and run it much faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altering the SQL query itself such that it only returns rows of that date would look something like...

`select * from table_to_be_converted_into_a_df where date = '2021-07-07';`

This will reduce the total amount of data returned from the DB to your python script—which could significantly speed up your script. However, if your table `table_to_be_converted_into_a_df` does NOT have an index on the `date` column, then your query will still be scanning *the entire* table, which may take a while.

If thats the case consider adding an index to the `date` column.

Comment: Amazing ! I tried your code and I have my result in less than  3 seconds from 20 minutes sounds like a good improvement to me :)

Comment: @chris is it possible to add index in access db ?

Comment: @hackwithharsha https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce